# How to batch write to database every N pages with ReactiveExtensions Range and WithAsync

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following function that is working well... however given the amount of data it is generating, i need to batch write to a database every 10 or so pages fetched.

```
var start = DateTime.Now;

IList<AggV2> list = null;

var lastRan = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-6); // get dummy date 6 months ago
var daysToRun = (DateTime.UtcNow - lastRan).Days;

try
{
    IObservable<IList<AggV2>> query =
        Observable
            .Using(
                () => new HttpClient(),
                hc =>
                    from day in
                        Observable
                            .Range(1, daysToRun)
                            .Select(day =>
                                Observable
                                    .FromAsync(ct => PolygonWebApi.GetGroupedDailyBarsAsync(hc, this.apiKey, Locale.US, Market.Stocks, lastRan.AddDays(day), false, ct))
                                    .Select(r =>
                                    {
                                        this.logger.LogInformation("got {0} records for {1}", r.Results.Count(), lastRan.AddDays(day));
                                        return new TickersResponseWithDay(lastRan.AddDays(day), r);
                                    }))
                            .Merge(MaxConcurrentDownloads)
                    from tv2 in day.AggregateResponse.Results
                    select tv2)
            .ToList();

    list = await query.ToTask(cancellationToken);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
catch (Exception e) { this.logger.LogError(e, e.Message); }

var duration = DateTime.Now - start;

if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    this.logger.LogInformation("{0} cancelled after {1}, database not updated", this.GetType().Name, duration.Humanize());
else
{
    this.logger.LogInformation("{0} downloaded {1} tickers in {2}, saving to database...", this.GetType().Name, list.Count, duration.Humanize());
    await SaveTickersToDatabaseAsync(list, cts.Token);
}
```

Instead of getting all the data and then writing, I would like to call `SaveTickersToDatabaseAsync(list, cancellationToken)` every 10 pages.

I would also need to be able to exit out of the application at any point `cancellationToken` is set.

Is it possible to combine the above batching and cancellation requirements please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple with the use of `.Buffer(10)`. However, by pushing the `SaveTickersToDatabaseAsync` into the query (which is the right thing to do) you're making your overall error handling and logging increasingly irrelevant at the end of the method. I'd suggest suggest trying to remove it and try to put it all in the query.

Here's what the code needs to look like:

```
IObservable<IList<Unit>> query =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new HttpClient(),
            hc =>
                from day in
                    Observable
                        .Range(1, daysToRun)
                        .Select(day =>
                            Observable
                                .FromAsync(ct => PolygonWebApi.GetGroupedDailyBarsAsync(hc, this.apiKey, Locale.US, Market.Stocks, lastRan.AddDays(day), false, ct))
                                .Do(r => this.logger.LogInformation("got {0} records for {1}", r.Results.Count(), lastRan.AddDays(day)))
                                .Select(r => new TickersResponseWithDay(lastRan.AddDays(day), r)))
                        .Merge(MaxConcurrentDownloads)
                from tv2 in day.AggregateResponse.Results
                select tv2)
        .Buffer(10)
        .SelectMany(xs => Observable.FromAsync(ct => SaveTickersToDatabaseAsync(xs, ct)))
        .ToList();

IList<Unit> list = await query.ToTask(cancellationToken);
```

Now, you should also consider using a normal `Subscribe` rather than the `query.ToTask(cancellationToken)` to run the query.

Your code would look like this:

```
IObservable<Unit> query =
    Observable
        .Defer(() =>
        {
            var lastRan = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-6); // get dummy date 6 months ago
            var daysToRun = (DateTime.UtcNow - lastRan).Days;
            
            return
                Observable
                    .Using(
                        () => new HttpClient(),
                        hc =>
                            from day in
                                Observable
                                    .Range(1, daysToRun)
                                    .Select(day =>
                                        Observable
                                            .FromAsync(ct => PolygonWebApi.GetGroupedDailyBarsAsync(hc, this.apiKey, Locale.US, Market.Stocks, lastRan.AddDays(day), false, ct))
                                            .Do(r => this.logger.LogInformation("got {0} records for {1}", r.Results.Count(), lastRan.AddDays(day)))
                                            .Select(r => new TickersResponseWithDay(lastRan.AddDays(day), r)))
                                    .Merge(MaxConcurrentDownloads)
                            from tv2 in day.AggregateResponse.Results
                            select tv2)
                    .Buffer(10)
                    .SelectMany(xs => Observable.FromAsync(ct => SaveTickersToDatabaseAsync(xs, ct)));
        });

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Subscribe(
            x => { /* each call to `SaveTickersToDatabaseAsync` runs this code */  },
            ex => { /* an exception? then end here */ },
            () => { /* successfully completed */ });
```

That's clean and self contained and it's the Rx way of doing things.